# getBoundingClientRect() on two React components and check if they overlap onScroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to get a `ref`, more specifically a `getBoundingClientRect()` on the `<Header/>` and `<Testimonials/>` component. I then want to watch for a scroll event and check if the two components ever overlap. Currently, my overlap variable never flips to true even if what appears on the page is that the two components are overlaping.

```
  const [isIntersecting, setIsIntersecting] = useState(false)
 
  const header = useRef(null)
  const testimonials = useRef(null)


  const scrollHandler = _ => {
    let headerRect = header.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    let testiRect = testimonials.current.getBoundingClientRect();

    let overlap = !(headerRect.right < testiRect.left ||
      headerRect.left > testiRect.right ||
      headerRect.bottom < testiRect.top ||
      headerRect.top > testiRect.bottom)

    console.log(overlap) // never flips to true
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler, true);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler, true);
    };
  }, []);

const App = () => {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <LandingPage />
      <div style={{ height: '100vh', backgroundColor: 'black', color: 'white' }}>
      </div>
      <AboutPage />
      <TestimonialsPage />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Components can not have ```refs``` in that way. They can be accessed with a ```forwardRef```, but im not sure of the correct syntax when all i really want to do is get the ```BoundingClientRect()```

Comment: you can `useRef` in your `Header.jsx` against your outer div and then retrieve the bounds. Might help to explain where you want to use these bounds?

Comment: @Pellay I have made some updates to my original post!

Comment: then you need to forward the ref back to the parent: https://javascript.plainenglish.io/using-forwardref-with-react-hooks-9d0d096ad810

Comment: Why would the component's overlap? Why would their bounding rects change when you scroll?

Comment: That doesn't answer my question at all, specifically why would you need to check on scroll?

Comment: @Phil my header is fixed on the page, as I scroll the header should be overlapping any components on the page

Comment: Use intersection observer for that kind of check. In any case, if you are not passing refs to your Header and TestimonialsPage how do you expect it to work ?

Comment: @CesarePolonara great idea but I don't think you can use an intersection observer between siblings and especially if one is `position: fixed`

Comment: @Phil Why shouldn't it work ? IO can watch for viewport and you can set a rootMargin to the viewport box, since a fixed element is fixed to viewport. you just have to set margins accordingly to your fixed element position: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pqujuz?file=src%2FApp.js
(rootMargin doesn't work properly inside an iframe as on stacblktz)

Comment: @CesarePolonara I was trying the same on CodeSandbox. Didn't realise it was the sandbox causing the problem

Comment: Yeah it's iframe related !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **First**: Components can't receive directly a *ref* prop, unless you are wrapping the Component itself in a *React.forwardRef* wrapper:

  ```
   const Component = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
      <button ref={ref}>
        {props.children}
      </button>
    ));

    // Inside your Parent Component:

    const ref = useRef();
    <Component ref={ref}>Click me!</Component>;
  ```
- **Second**: you can also pass a *ref* down to a child as a standard prop, but you can't call that prop ***ref*** since that's a special reserved word just like the ***key*** prop:

  ```
  const Component= (props) => (
         <button ref={props.myRef}>
           {props.children}
         </button>
       );

       // Inside your Parent Component

       const ref = useRef();
       <Component myRef={ref}>Click me!</Component>;
  ```
- This works perfectly fine, and if it's a your personal project you
  might work like this with no issues, the only downside is that you
  have to use custom prop name for those refs, so the code  gets harder to
  read and to mantain, especially if it's a shared repo.
- **Third**: Now that you learnt how to gain access to the DOM node of a child Component from its parent, you must know that even if usually it's safe to perform manipulations on those nodes inside a *useEffect* ( or a *componentDidMount* ) since they are executed once the DOM has rendered, to be 100% sure you will have access to the right DOM node it's always better using a callback as a ref like this:

  ```
   const handleRef = (node) => {
   if (node) //do something with node
   };
   <Component ref={handleRef}/>
  ```
- Basically your function *hanldeRef* will be called by React during
  DOM node render by passing the node itself as its first parameter,
  this way you can perform a safe check on the node, and be sure it's
  100% valorized when you are going to perform your DOM manipulation.
- Concerning your specific question about how to access the *getBoundingClientRect* of a child Component DOM node, I made a working example with both the approaches:
  https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pqujuz

Comment: This has already been explained and rejected by the OP. I've linked to an article that explains how to forward refs and it's still not right apparently.

Comment: He totally changed the question...

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to define each of your components as [Forwarding Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html), eg

```tsx
const Header = forwardRef<HTMLElement>((_, ref) => (
  <header ref={ref}>
    <h1>I am the header</h1>
  </header>
));
```

You can then pass a `HTMLElement` ref to your components to refer to later

```tsx
const headerRef = useRef<HTMLElement>(null);

const scrollHandler = () => {
  console.log("header position", headerRef.current?.getBoundingClientRect());
};

useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler);
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler);
  };
}, []);

return (
  <Header ref={headerRef} />
);
```

<sub>I'm using TypeScript examples since it's easier to translate back down to JS than it is to go up to TS</sub>

Comment: What about for a scrollEvent?

Comment: @Ben_Sven_Ten that wasn't there in your original question. I need time to update it